# How to add image created from canvas element to page?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

A project requires a canvas element be converted to an image. I'm having some issues and trying to create a simple project where I can do some experiments. This project should convert the canvas element to an image and append it to a div but it doesn't seem to work. See code below What do I do?

Thanks,
Matt

```js
/**
 *    Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen
 *    Abidas Software
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Demonstrates how to download a canvas an image with a single
 * direct click on a link.
 */
function doCanvas() {
    /* draw something */
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Code Project IE', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
    ctx.font = '26px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Click link above to save this as image', 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
}


function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  var imgData =  canvas.toDataURL();
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = split_4;
  img.src = imgData;
  img.appendTo($('#imagediv'));

}


 function split_4() {

         
  alert('did something happen?')

        };

/** 
 * The event handler for the link's onclick event. We give THIS as a
 * parameter (=the link element), ID of the canvas and a filename.
*/
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'test.png');
}, false);

/**
 * Draw something to canvas
 */
doCanvas();
```

```css
 body {
     background-color:#555557;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     overflow:hidden;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 }
 canvas {
     border:1px solid #000;
     float:left;
     clear:both;
 }
 #download {
     float:left;
     cursor:pointer;
     color:#ccc;
     padding:3px;
 }
 #download:hover {
     color:#fff;
 }
 /*
 div, input {
     font-size:16px;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     border:1px solid #000;
     border-radius: 5px;
     float:left;
     padding:5px;
     width:50px;
     margin:1px 1px;
     background-color:#bbb;
 }
 input[type='text'] {
     font-size:16px;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:70px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#fff;
     padding-bottom:4px;
 }
 input[type='button'] {
     font-size:16px;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:110px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#333;
     color:#eee;
     padding-bottom:4px;
 }
 input[type='button']:hover {
     background-color:#fff463;
     color:#000;
 }
 input[type='range'] {
     width:100px;
     margin:0 0 0 10px;
 }
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="download">Click to Create and Append Image from Canvas Element</a>
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas">Sorry, no canvas available</canvas>
<div id="imagediv"></div>
```

Comment: Did you check your Developer Tools? They give you a pretty good idea of what the problem is.

Comment: Isn't img.appendTo($('#imagediv')); more supposed to be something like $('#imagediv').appendTo(img) or something jquery like... img has no function appendTo in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `img.appendTo($('#imagediv'));`, do `$('#imagediv').append(img);`. Cheers!

```js
/**
 *    Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen
 *    Abidas Software
*/
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/**
 * Demonstrates how to download a canvas an image with a single
 * direct click on a link.
 */
function doCanvas() {
    /* draw something */
    ctx.fillStyle = '#f90';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
    ctx.font = '60px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Code Project IE', 10, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
    ctx.font = '26px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillText('Click link above to save this as image', 15, canvas.height / 2 + 35);
}


function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
  var imgData =  canvas.toDataURL();
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = split_4;
  img.src = imgData;
  $('#imagediv').append(img);

}


 function split_4() {

         
  alert('did something happen?')

        };

/** 
 * The event handler for the link's onclick event. We give THIS as a
 * parameter (=the link element), ID of the canvas and a filename.
*/
document.getElementById('download').addEventListener('click', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', 'test.png');
}, false);

/**
 * Draw something to canvas
 */
doCanvas();
```

```css
 body {
     background-color:#555557;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     overflow:hidden;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
 }
 canvas {
     border:1px solid #000;
     float:left;
     clear:both;
 }
 #download {
     float:left;
     cursor:pointer;
     color:#ccc;
     padding:3px;
 }
 #download:hover {
     color:#fff;
 }
 /*
 div, input {
     font-size:16px;
     font-family:sans-serif;
     border:1px solid #000;
     border-radius: 5px;
     float:left;
     padding:5px;
     width:50px;
     margin:1px 1px;
     background-color:#bbb;
 }
 input[type='text'] {
     font-size:16px;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:70px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#fff;
     padding-bottom:4px;
 }
 input[type='button'] {
     font-size:16px;
     font-weight:bold;
     width:110px;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#333;
     color:#eee;
     padding-bottom:4px;
 }
 input[type='button']:hover {
     background-color:#fff463;
     color:#000;
 }
 input[type='range'] {
     width:100px;
     margin:0 0 0 10px;
 }
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="download">Click to Create and Append Image from Canvas Element</a>
<canvas width="500" height="300" id="canvas">Sorry, no canvas available</canvas>
<div id="imagediv"></div>
```